# Why does my website automatically overide my CSS height?

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists

Basically, I have this code:

```
<li style = "height: 250px;"> <p>Foo</p></li>
```

However, when I go to the site, it doesn't seem to change. So I inspect the element in chrome and it says this:
`<li style = "height: 180px;"> <p>Foo</p></li>`

I have properly saved and uploaded the file, refreshed it without cache and in incognito. I have also tried other browsers, but it still overwrites it somehow!!

What can I do to overwrite the `180px` height and put make it `250px`, as I have tried everything, and it doesn't work!!

Comment: when you get that from your server in different browsers, you can assume that something with the upload of the new version went most probably wrong.. maybe compare timestamps of the file (local and server file)

Comment: If you were using Firefox + Firebug addon, I would tell you to check if your CSS file was actually loaded, also you could inspect where the current element is getting it's settings from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you show your `HTML` `markup` for better understanding, but right now you can use `!important` like this:

```
<li style = "height: 250px !important;"> <p>Foo</p></li>
```

It will override your style.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an IDE problem rather than your files themselves. Did you try other IDE's or even manually FTP-upload the file? Also be positive it's the right file and not some copy you uploaded by accident. I've had this myself only to notice I was actually uploading the same file in a different directory.

Also try to add `<h1>Test</h1>` or something at the top to check your file changes. If that doesn't show up also, you can be sure there's something wrong with your FTP.